# Hooks aren’t pulling on cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation, hook-modifier

I have been doing a tutorial on cloth reveal on an object, and I’ve made the cloth, physics and stuff but I’m stuck at the part of the hooks pulling on the cloth to reveal the object. In my case the hooks don’t do anything after I’ve set the animation, they act as if they aren’t hooked to the cloth. Anyone can help?

Comment: because you didn't showed us any settings you made - we can just guess: so my guess is: your hook modifier is after the cloth modifier, but it should be before. if this doesn't help, pls provide blend file so we don't have to ask what you did and check it out ourselves. thx. also you should provide the tutorial link....

Comment: As Chris mentioned, we have no idea what you did... my only guess apart from maybe incorrect order of modifiers could be, well - you did not do it as described in the tutorial (which would include having them in incorrect order for example). Since you say they act as if they aren't hooked to the cloth, then this might simply be the case because something went wrong when you tried to hook the cloth to them.

Comment: Maybe you need to put the Hook modifiers before the Cloth modifier, hard to tell with sofew informations

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Put the *Cloth* modifier below the *Hook* modifiers
- Create a pin group